# In Apache Spark 2.4. How to force the driver logger to use the latest renewed kerberos delegation token to write to HDFS, instead of an outdated one?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, kerberos-delegation

One of our Spark application frequently ran into kerberos authentication error on a Hadoop cluster. Initially we believed it to be caused by a misconfigured delegation token renewal policy. But later we found the following message in the Spark driver log:

```
22/01/15 02:13:38 INFO YARNHadoopDelegationTokenManager: Attempting to login to KDC using principal: XXX/ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal@CDHDP.COM
22/01/15 02:13:38 INFO YARNHadoopDelegationTokenManager: Successfully logged into KDC.
22/01/15 02:13:38 INFO HadoopFSDelegationTokenProvider: getting token for: DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-206445389_46, ugi=XXX/ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal@CDHDP.COM (auth:KERBEROS)]] with renewer yarn/ip-172-31-34-136.us-west-2.compute.internal@CDHDP.COM
22/01/15 02:13:38 INFO YARNHadoopDelegationTokenManager: Scheduling renewal in 3.7 min.
22/01/15 02:13:38 INFO YARNHadoopDelegationTokenManager: Updating delegation tokens.
22/01/15 02:13:38 INFO SparkHadoopUtil: Updating delegation tokens for current user.
22/01/15 02:17:23 INFO YARNHadoopDelegationTokenManager: Attempting to login to KDC using principal: XXX/ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal@CDHDP.COM
22/01/15 02:17:23 INFO YARNHadoopDelegationTokenManager: Successfully logged into KDC.
22/01/15 02:17:23 INFO HadoopFSDelegationTokenProvider: getting token for: DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1775743108_46, ugi=XXX/ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal@CDHDP.COM (auth:KERBEROS)]] with renewer yarn/ip-172-31-34-136.us-west-2.compute.internal@CDHDP.COM
22/01/15 02:17:23 INFO YARNHadoopDelegationTokenManager: Scheduling renewal in 3.7 min.
22/01/15 02:17:23 INFO YARNHadoopDelegationTokenManager: Updating delegation tokens.
22/01/15 02:17:23 INFO SparkHadoopUtil: Updating delegation tokens for current user.
22/01/15 02:17:28 ERROR DriverLogger$DfsAsyncWriter: Failed writing driver logs to dfs
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken): token (token for XXX: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=XXX/ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal@CDHDP.COM, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1642212592939, maxDate=1642212892939, sequenceNumber=25145, masterKeyId=237) is expired, current time: 2022-01-15 02:17:28,048+0000 expected renewal time: 2022-01-15 02:14:52,939+0000
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:228)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:497)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1085)/* w */
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1865)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1668)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
22/01/15 02:17:33 ERROR DriverLogger$DfsAsyncWriter: Failed writing driver logs to dfs
```

So the error of DriverLogger was triggered only 5 seconds after a successful renewal (at which point the latest token couldn't possibly expire), for the same hadoop user. So the only possibility seems to be that the DriverLogger tried to write into HDFS using an obsolete delegation token.

How could I confirm this hypothesis and how to fix it?

**UPDATE 1** The above log is from launching a Spark ThriftServer in a YARN environment (using ./sbin/start-thriftserver). The strange thing is that if I submit a normal application (e.g. the SparkPi example), the problem disappeared even after prolonged execution.

So part of the Spark ThriftServer could be written with errors that causes the token used by DriverLogger to be out of sync. I just don't know which part. So the question becomes: what are possible ways to ensure that the token being renewed and the token being used for the HDFS writing are the same token?

Comment: Are the clocks sync'd in the cluster?

Comment: I believe so, plus this problem appears on Spark driver, not workers

Comment: I suggest run a quick check, clock drift happens and can cause these types of issues.  It's usually easy and quick to rule out, so worth checking first.

Comment: Yes one of my colleague have verified that the time on driver and master are synchronised

Comment: From the logs this is supposed to happen.  The token should have been renewed 4 minutes before.  Is the thrift server under heavy load?  or is there anything else running on the thrift server that may be consuming a lot of resources?

Comment: Could you provide more logs?  When was the last time that HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN was successfully intiailized / renewed and what time did it say it needed to be renewed?